# R subset today data with lubridate

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, subset, lubridate

I want to read a data set with meteo data recorded every ten minutes. I manage to read and paste day and hour of record in a single date column. But I can't find how to subset today data. This is the code I'm trying

```
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)

datos.full<-read.csv(data_file,header=FALSE)
colnames(datos.full)<-c("cod","year","dayofyear","hour","tempc","relhum","velwind","dirwind","sigwd","sigwv","vmaxwind","u","v","precip","bat")

# Subset 2017
datos.year <- subset(datos.full, datos.full$year == 2017)

# Move from year and day of year to full date format
datos.year$day<-as.Date(datos.year$dayofyear, origin = "2016-12-31")
# Add leading zeros to hour (so they are four digits)
datos.year$hour<-str_pad(datos.year$hour, 4, pad = "0")

# Paste day and hour, parse date_time
datos.year$fechahora <- paste(datos.year$day, datos.year$hour)
datos.year$fechahora <- parse_date_time(datos.year$fechahora, 'Y-m-d HM')

# Filter by today (from lubridate)
datos.today<-datos.year %>% 
  filter( datos.year$day == today())

datos.today<-as.data.frame(datos.today)
```

But when I get here, datos.year and datos.today have the same dimensions, no filtering has been done at all. Maybe it is related to day format but I'm not sure how to deal with it

```
str(datos.year$day)
Date[1:24286], format: "2017-01-01" "2017-01-01" "2017-01-01" "2017-01-01" "2017-01-01" ...
```

Thanks for your help

Data for 2017  (subset of last 200 rows)

```
dput(datos.year)
structure(list(cod = c(101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L), year = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L), dayofyear = c(169L, 
169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 
169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 
169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 
169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 
169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 
169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 
169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 
169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 
169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 
169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 
169L, 169L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 
170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 
170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 
170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 
170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 
170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 
170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 
170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 
170L), hour = c("0510", "0520", "0530", "0540", "0550", "0600", 
"0610", "0620", "0630", "0640", "0650", "0700", "0710", "0720", 
"0730", "0740", "0750", "0800", "0810", "0820", "0830", "0840", 
"0850", "0900", "0910", "0920", "0930", "0940", "0950", "1000", 
"1010", "1020", "1030", "1040", "1050", "1100", "1110", "1120", 
"1130", "1140", "1150", "1200", "1210", "1220", "1230", "1240", 
"1250", "1300", "1310", "1320", "1330", "1340", "1350", "1400", 
"1410", "1420", "1430", "1440", "1450", "1500", "1510", "1520", 
"1530", "1540", "1550", "1600", "1610", "1620", "1630", "1640", 
"1650", "1700", "1710", "1720", "1730", "1740", "1750", "1800", 
"1810", "1820", "1830", "1840", "1850", "1900", "1910", "1920", 
"1930", "1940", "1950", "2000", "2010", "2020", "2030", "2040", 
"2050", "2100", "2110", "2120", "2130", "2140", "2150", "2200", 
"2210", "2220", "2230", "2240", "2250", "2300", "2310", "2320", 
"2330", "2340", "2350", "0000", "0010", "0020", "0030", "0040", 
"0050", "0100", "0110", "0120", "0130", "0140", "0150", "0200", 
"0210", "0220", "0230", "0240", "0250", "0300", "0310", "0320", 
"0330", "0340", "0350", "0400", "0410", "0420", "0430", "0440", 
"0450", "0500", "0510", "0520", "0530", "0540", "0550", "0600", 
"0610", "0620", "0630", "0640", "0650", "0700", "0710", "0720", 
"0730", "0740", "0750", "0800", "0810", "0820", "0830", "0840", 
"0850", "0900", "0910", "0920", "0930", "0940", "0950", "1000", 
"1010", "1020", "1030", "1040", "1050", "1100", "1110", "1120", 
"1130", "1140", "1150", "1200", "1210", "1220", "1230", "1240", 
"1250", "1300", "1310", "1320", "1330", "1340", "1350", "1400", 
"1410", "1420"), tempc = c(16.59, 17.2, 18.08, 18.84, 19.92, 
20.68, 21.52, 22.25, 22.8, 23.04, 23.9, 24.78, 25.01, 25.12, 
25.8, 26.06, 27.43, 28.17, 28.78, 28.7, 28.65, 29.16, 29.3, 28.95, 
29.57, 29.56, 29.34, 29.55, 29.82, 30.33, 30.66, 30.36, 30.1, 
30.02, 29.88, 30.72, 31.4, 31.61, 31.82, 32.01, 32.4, 32.15, 
31.54, 32.29, 32.77, 32.16, 32.3, 32.25, 32.11, 31.94, 32.31, 
32.71, 32.39, 32.05, 32.19, 32.19, 32.11, 31.85, 31.97, 31.72, 
31.07, 31.81, 31.47, 30.81, 30.71, 31.1, 30.61, 30.89, 30.85, 
30.69, 30.58, 30.42, 29.98, 29.63, 29.56, 29.09, 28.46, 27.54, 
26.87, 26.62, 26.23, 25.89, 25.65, 25.41, 25.15, 24.91, 24.51, 
24.11, 23.81, 23.46, 23.05, 22.71, 22.1, 21.77, 21.33, 21.11, 
20.97, 20.73, 20.96, 20.94, 20.55, 20.04, 20.39, 20.2, 20.05, 
19.83, 18.93, 19.2, 19.26, 18.85, 18.52, 18.26, 17.91, 18, 18.12, 
18.35, 18.22, 18.09, 17.76, 17.91, 18.1, 17.88, 16.88, 16.69, 
16.54, 16.41, 16.14, 16.09, 16.08, 16.1, 16.27, 16.36, 16.33, 
16.33, 16.38, 16.19, 15.9, 15.9, 15.81, 15.53, 15.32, 15.31, 
15.19, 15.32, 15.93, 16.89, 17.75, 18.41, 18.8, 19.35, 19.99, 
20.83, 21.24, 21.54, 22.33, 23.01, 23.5, 23.98, 25.01, 24.94, 
25.06, 25.42, 26.44, 26.4, 26.92, 26.74, 26.67, 26.95, 27.34, 
27.84, 28.7, 28.92, 29.02, 29.21, 29.2, 29.21, 29.45, 29.38, 
29.81, 30.1, 29.76, 30.41, 30.33, 29.95, 30.73, 30.17, 30.55, 
30.92, 31.42, 31.28, 30.75, 30.87, 31.44, 31.47, 31.88, 31.86, 
32.14, 32.27, 32.35, 32.29), relhum = c(84.4, 81.8, 76.9, 75.28, 
71.4, 66.74, 63.16, 60.16, 58.37, 56.97, 53.97, 50.57, 50.64, 
49.16, 46.93, 45.3, 41.29, 38.7, 36.27, 35.55, 33.98, 33.12, 
32.05, 32.19, 31.09, 31.25, 31.45, 31.2, 30.46, 30.59, 30.5, 
31.55, 31.9, 32.61, 32.47, 31.59, 30.48, 30.04, 29.36, 29.06, 
28.28, 29.12, 31.16, 29.6, 30.52, 31.24, 31.43, 31.81, 31.99, 
32.4, 31.7, 30.92, 31.1, 30.82, 30.07, 29.68, 29.71, 29.78, 29.08, 
29.79, 30.67, 29.34, 29.29, 29.71, 29.32, 27.76, 27.76, 27.35, 
26.79, 26.99, 27.26, 27.04, 28.12, 29.03, 28.78, 30.16, 31.21, 
32.79, 33.79, 33.75, 34.39, 33.99, 34.46, 35.86, 37.29, 39.21, 
41.29, 43.07, 44.73, 46.57, 48.29, 49.89, 53.54, 54.71, 57.79, 
58.55, 59.55, 59.97, 58.54, 59.26, 61.01, 63.12, 60.74, 61.89, 
62.6, 63.62, 67.75, 65.42, 64.8, 66.59, 68.35, 69.32, 71.91, 
70.76, 69.58, 67.93, 68.08, 69.01, 69.44, 66.51, 64.73, 66.55, 
73.18, 74.03, 75.4, 74.8, 76.7, 78.13, 76.76, 75.71, 72.94, 71.91, 
73, 73.23, 73.07, 73.19, 73.57, 73.16, 73.14, 74.26, 75.12, 75.81, 
76.77, 76.85, 74.19, 70.69, 66.4, 64.53, 62.33, 60.36, 57.38, 
54.3, 54.15, 53.49, 50.34, 47.44, 46.31, 44.24, 41.14, 41.1, 
41.75, 40.75, 37.65, 37.69, 36.74, 37.44, 38.13, 37.36, 36.5, 
34.93, 32.81, 32.63, 32.42, 32.75, 33.27, 34.18, 35.11, 34.86, 
35.47, 34.86, 34.4, 33.86, 34.64, 34.51, 32.76, 34.43, 35.12, 
35.93, 34.54, 34.6, 35.64, 34.95, 32.9, 33.11, 32.31, 31.57, 
30.76, 30.74, 30.29, 29.74), velwind = c(0.989, 0.827, 1.106, 
0.857, 0.844, 0.594, 0.587, 0.67, 0.747, 0.481, 0.348, 0.338, 
0.945, 1.057, 1.246, 0.921, 1.126, 0.999, 2.26, 2.481, 3.195, 
3.522, 2.598, 3.45, 3.251, 3.734, 3.491, 4.071, 3.255, 2.932, 
3.714, 3.722, 4.065, 3.287, 3.297, 2.636, 2.811, 3.423, 3.064, 
3.543, 3.414, 3.151, 3.266, 4.098, 4.056, 4.589, 4.017, 4.696, 
4.541, 4.944, 4.652, 4.699, 5.138, 4.994, 4.488, 4.683, 5.266, 
4.81, 4.977, 4.554, 5.26, 5.106, 5.244, 4.756, 5.376, 5.256, 
4.918, 4.64, 4.452, 4.271, 4.42, 4.584, 4.118, 3.982, 4.517, 
4.452, 4.501, 4.459, 4.153, 3.831, 3.607, 3.432, 3.177, 2.867, 
2.439, 2.123, 1.824, 1.889, 1.51, 1.551, 1.903, 1.535, 0.592, 
0.515, 0.588, 0.613, 1.09, 1.118, 1.56, 1.398, 1.127, 0.7, 1.369, 
1.369, 1.727, 1.129, 0.952, 1.216, 1.118, 0.963, 0.663, 0.707, 
1.364, 1.439, 1.375, 0.968, 1.221, 0.985, 1.677, 1.636, 2.122, 
1.436, 0.839, 0.856, 0.746, 1.371, 1.04, 0.823, 0.815, 1.186, 
1.128, 1.174, 1.52, 1.31, 0.931, 0.818, 1.061, 1.156, 0.788, 
0.842, 0.521, 0.513, 0.811, 1.178, 1.095, 0.377, 0.595, 0.692, 
1.08, 1.194, 1.216, 0.687, 0.851, 0.883, 0.595, 0.66, 0.727, 
0.656, 0.837, 0.869, 0.873, 0.947, 1.172, 1.315, 1.923, 1.529, 
2.264, 1.823, 2.158, 2.636, 2.749, 2.989, 2.702, 2.818, 3.084, 
3.198, 3.244, 3.365, 2.789, 3.664, 2.931, 3.151, 3.466, 3.804, 
3.495, 3.147, 4.035, 2.614, 4.198, 4.185, 3.866, 3.732, 3.888, 
3.663, 4.457, 4.527, 3.907, 4.281, 4.698, 4.858), dirwind = c(0.778, 
341.4, 332, 274.7, 352.8, 312.2, 255.1, 290.1, 301, 23.58, 61.21, 
9.29, 211.3, 196.7, 203.4, 174.6, 127.3, 105.8, 112, 101.1, 103.7, 
120.1, 123.2, 100.3, 121.9, 115.4, 98.3, 103.8, 121.8, 129.3, 
131, 109.4, 101.2, 83, 80.8, 106.5, 137.5, 130, 122.9, 135.6, 
133.7, 125.3, 93.5, 129.3, 126.1, 115.7, 111, 114.1, 105.3, 109, 
126.3, 126.2, 117.6, 114.4, 134.8, 110.6, 117.8, 122.2, 117.6, 
114.3, 103.6, 124.2, 131.1, 100.3, 112.1, 115.7, 109.9, 114.8, 
113.9, 115.7, 119, 116.3, 114.2, 111.3, 124.9, 117.3, 118.6, 
110.7, 110.4, 111.4, 116, 106.3, 103.9, 105.6, 103.6, 101.3, 
103.5, 104.7, 91.1, 80.6, 80.1, 100, 128.7, 13.68, 336.1, 18.7, 
5.727, 28, 19.19, 14.19, 3.595, 20.45, 37.53, 46.49, 49.18, 26.93, 
23.51, 14.92, 2.505, 7.611, 357.2, 342, 314.9, 328.7, 320.9, 
333.2, 344.6, 347.5, 3.674, 8.76, 10.26, 350, 343.4, 27.27, 0.337, 
344.6, 316.8, 336.6, 23.48, 358.6, 337, 350, 330.8, 321.7, 343.9, 
358.2, 348.7, 319.3, 318.4, 280.6, 335.2, 350.7, 13.89, 333.1, 
311.6, 310.7, 351.3, 353.9, 355.4, 352.9, 333.8, 276.8, 258, 
239, 235.7, 244.9, 240.9, 277.7, 212.8, 186.1, 197.7, 174.6, 
155.3, 168.9, 133.6, 132.2, 168.2, 170.4, 136.1, 158.9, 136.6, 
137.2, 141.5, 129.7, 130.6, 129.6, 135.2, 105.6, 123.3, 128.3, 
119.5, 134.8, 113.8, 101.7, 142.8, 97.7, 109.6, 106.8, 157.4, 
123, 101, 110.6, 122, 98.5, 117.8, 106.9, 122.9, 122.8, 114.3, 
132.6), sigwd = c(16.51, 32.83, 16.66, 27.98, 79.63, 60.28, 23.69, 
24.5, 45.32, 39.62, 70.1, 90.1, 23.58, 21.52, 24.93, 29.27, 37.55, 
27.02, 24.24, 19.62, 13.81, 15.1, 17.77, 23.68, 15.11, 20.28, 
31.35, 13.71, 25.67, 23.51, 16.58, 28.2, 24.23, 20.55, 23.3, 
21.65, 19.57, 22.7, 21.9, 19.52, 23.69, 20.49, 23.87, 14.77, 
22.5, 13.21, 24.81, 13.6, 17.3, 17.74, 14.98, 12.67, 11.34, 19.36, 
14.6, 22.34, 11.11, 10.46, 18.9, 16.36, 15.25, 11.92, 12.11, 
16.23, 10.61, 9.78, 11.75, 11.25, 15.47, 11.04, 15.67, 12.43, 
11.34, 17.2, 10.15, 11.01, 9.62, 8.69, 9.63, 7.897, 7.037, 7.515, 
7.233, 7.104, 7.575, 8.68, 7.759, 7.006, 8.02, 6.518, 3.612, 
8.8, 13.12, 63.5, 11.36, 27.22, 6.64, 10.37, 8.09, 6.317, 13.48, 
18.15, 11.95, 7.212, 4.327, 17.07, 11.04, 10.56, 9.6, 5.738, 
4.379, 7.192, 8.48, 7.963, 11.12, 9.63, 5.959, 7.303, 5.773, 
3.731, 4.263, 11.52, 18.02, 10.52, 16.48, 29.78, 10.99, 22.12, 
13.65, 9.59, 11.44, 13.65, 12.65, 8.3, 14.51, 6.4, 9.21, 19.05, 
8.84, 14.36, 15.07, 14.02, 20.15, 11.35, 13.7, 28.56, 9.05, 16.85, 
10.89, 11.23, 20.49, 21.45, 16.48, 20.07, 48.83, 26.02, 30.16, 
51.06, 46.58, 32.04, 54.28, 35.29, 43.12, 29.53, 22.31, 42.66, 
35.04, 43.35, 43.98, 19.55, 13.7, 20.91, 25.84, 21.61, 24.75, 
20.51, 21.17, 18.44, 22.34, 11.28, 27.1, 22.04, 17.56, 18.22, 
22.31, 24.19, 27.7, 23.83, 18.7, 27.65, 16.33, 30.54, 30.84, 
22.07, 18.32, 25.6, 25.28, 17.37, 20.53, 12.79), sigwv = c(0.249, 
0.426, 0.202, 0.426, 0.485, 0.343, 0.174, 0.231, 0.26, 0.21, 
0.179, 0.229, 0.289, 0.341, 0.39, 0.482, 0.429, 0.369, 0.899, 
0.77, 0.76, 0.88, 0.848, 1.233, 0.901, 1.029, 0.898, 1.058, 0.95, 
1.048, 0.792, 1.049, 1.013, 0.944, 0.959, 0.912, 1.206, 1.352, 
1.144, 1.095, 1.196, 1.232, 1.192, 1.245, 1.458, 1.094, 1.604, 
1.162, 1.213, 1.561, 1.182, 0.878, 1.313, 0.974, 1.037, 0.999, 
1.143, 0.907, 1.178, 1.038, 1.181, 0.822, 1.039, 1.145, 1.095, 
1.095, 1.314, 0.969, 0.709, 0.962, 1.135, 0.807, 0.891, 0.847, 
0.808, 0.704, 0.736, 0.775, 0.796, 0.654, 0.55, 0.613, 0.553, 
0.564, 0.424, 0.478, 0.35, 0.257, 0.244, 0.218, 0.129, 0.191, 
0.218, 0.214, 0.111, 0.047, 0.166, 0.306, 0.332, 0.255, 0.279, 
0.254, 0.244, 0.17, 0.121, 0.305, 0.316, 0.386, 0.274, 0.157, 
0.099, 0.091, 0.341, 0.134, 0.131, 0.349, 0.22, 0.163, 0.236, 
0.201, 0.198, 0.49, 0.154, 0.13, 0.269, 0.229, 0.13, 0.332, 0.12, 
0.306, 0.214, 0.276, 0.189, 0.183, 0.188, 0.085, 0.15, 0.252, 
0.166, 0.295, 0.112, 0.078, 0.156, 0.235, 0.26, 0.167, 0.154, 
0.264, 0.184, 0.203, 0.271, 0.239, 0.193, 0.191, 0.289, 0.212, 
0.257, 0.289, 0.267, 0.445, 0.543, 0.471, 0.513, 0.508, 0.566, 
0.622, 0.938, 0.654, 0.821, 0.628, 1.021, 0.81, 0.712, 0.915, 
1.04, 0.969, 1.069, 1.188, 1.269, 0.979, 0.829, 1.092, 1.19, 
0.974, 1.06, 1.08, 1.825, 1.224, 1.236, 0.972, 1.402, 0.833, 
1.409, 1.152, 0.861, 1.419, 1.843, 1.332, 0.866, 1.406), vmaxwind = c(1.42, 
1.48, 1.436, 1.992, 1.774, 1.296, 1.11, 1.176, 1.352, 1.062, 
0.914, 0.792, 1.636, 1.786, 2.022, 2.126, 1.954, 1.97, 4.076, 
4.602, 5.258, 5.644, 4.608, 6.342, 5.274, 5.724, 5.594, 6.426, 
5.358, 5.07, 5.712, 5.908, 6.456, 5.568, 5.3, 4.756, 5.2, 6.316, 
5.058, 5.71, 5.878, 5.722, 5.906, 6.588, 7.736, 7.204, 6.91, 
7.182, 7.902, 8.54, 8.04, 6.788, 9.22, 7.402, 6.994, 7.772, 8.65, 
7.126, 7.126, 6.968, 8.39, 7.57, 7.938, 7.896, 7.632, 7.714, 
7.55, 7.228, 6.108, 6.566, 6.99, 6.606, 6.568, 5.85, 6.668, 6.082, 
5.86, 6.174, 5.842, 5.592, 4.602, 5.012, 4.424, 4.128, 3.552, 
3.592, 2.858, 2.794, 2.092, 1.956, 2.19, 1.856, 0.99, 0.896, 
0.88, 0.78, 1.356, 1.924, 2.336, 1.946, 1.832, 1.338, 1.824, 
1.734, 1.924, 1.68, 1.574, 2.058, 2.146, 1.298, 0.904, 0.956, 
1.764, 1.792, 1.674, 1.712, 1.732, 1.264, 2.05, 2.15, 2.492, 
2.374, 1.15, 1.068, 1.514, 1.782, 1.448, 1.422, 1.062, 1.81, 
1.838, 1.852, 1.978, 1.704, 1.38, 1.082, 1.394, 1.736, 1.258, 
1.526, 0.808, 0.698, 1.218, 1.846, 1.87, 0.864, 0.888, 1.216, 
1.596, 1.714, 1.794, 1.236, 1.23, 1.33, 1.204, 1.132, 1.534, 
1.294, 1.434, 1.834, 2.374, 2.184, 2.384, 2.434, 3.182, 3.554, 
4.246, 3.524, 4.164, 4.596, 4.956, 5.188, 4.38, 4.566, 5.968, 
5.656, 5.816, 6.064, 5.862, 5.528, 4.688, 6.046, 5.768, 6.498, 
6.888, 5.134, 7.602, 9.16, 8.61, 6.86, 6.644, 5.452, 8.46, 6.704, 
6.754, 7.248, 9.26, 6.83, 7.044, 7.462), u = c(0.025, 0.296, 
0.496, 0.768, 0.21, 0.34, 0.526, 0.578, 0.465, -0.121, -0.192, 
0.014, 0.454, 0.308, 0.407, -0.08, -0.835, -0.877, -1.916, -2.286, 
-3.011, -2.976, -2.082, -3.187, -2.66, -3.11, -2.955, -3.824, 
-2.443, -2.142, -2.722, -3.195, -3.648, -3.098, -3.02, -2.353, 
-1.752, -2.599, -2.41, -2.321, -2.315, -2.416, -3.015, -3.054, 
-3.045, -4.077, -3.465, -4.176, -4.188, -4.517, -3.685, -3.751, 
-4.455, -4.353, -3.116, -4.039, -4.58, -4.022, -4.222, -4.004, 
-4.962, -4.14, -3.843, -4.506, -4.897, -4.659, -4.544, -4.139, 
-3.943, -3.78, -3.737, -4.025, -3.683, -3.578, -3.654, -3.895, 
-3.89, -4.121, -3.847, -3.527, -3.221, -3.264, -3.062, -2.74, 
-2.349, -2.06, -1.757, -1.815, -1.495, -1.519, -1.87, -1.497, 
-0.459, -0.034, 0.218, -0.184, -0.101, -0.503, -0.534, -0.348, 
-0.113, -0.249, -0.8, -0.988, -1.303, -0.552, -0.374, -0.322, 
-0.063, -0.134, 0.031, 0.217, 0.948, 0.744, 0.852, 0.437, 0.324, 
0.206, -0.12, -0.247, -0.376, 0.163, 0.202, -0.373, 0.017, 0.263, 
0.693, 0.394, -0.317, 0.043, 0.432, 0.175, 0.716, 0.817, 0.25, 
0.028, 0.197, 0.707, 0.518, 0.81, 0.21, 0.081, -0.153, 0.547, 
0.785, 0.275, 0.09, 0.027, 0.097, 0.152, 0.467, 0.64, 0.799, 
0.723, 0.416, 0.54, 0.566, 0.492, 0.335, 0.09, 0.178, -0.072, 
-0.509, -0.159, -1.23, -0.883, -0.507, -0.353, -1.184, -0.889, 
-1.872, -1.913, -1.507, -2.056, -2.213, -2.318, -2.305, -3.051, 
-2.277, -2.809, -2.226, -2.22, -3.089, -3.556, -2.081, -2.909, 
-3.437, -2.222, -1.595, -3.199, -3.707, -2.963, -2.873, -3.336, 
-3.792, -3.891, -2.963, -3.423, -3.997, -3.565), v = c(-0.95, 
-0.739, -0.942, -0.152, -0.48, -0.311, 0.123, -0.225, -0.318, 
-0.369, -0.057, -0.092, 0.741, 0.948, 1.077, 0.852, 0.549, 0.259, 
0.924, 0.525, 0.767, 1.689, 1.357, 0.489, 1.674, 1.638, 0.531, 
1.032, 1.644, 1.635, 2.301, 1.026, 0.854, -0.317, -0.321, 0.793, 
2.013, 1.924, 1.644, 2.429, 2.128, 1.764, 0.107, 2.542, 2.294, 
1.846, 1.457, 1.877, 1.15, 1.472, 2.575, 2.634, 2.359, 1.818, 
3.041, 1.609, 2.406, 2.495, 2.164, 1.791, 1.138, 2.804, 3.403, 
0.822, 2.014, 2.27, 1.613, 1.899, 1.732, 1.829, 2.082, 1.965, 
1.662, 1.288, 2.541, 1.985, 2.134, 1.573, 1.411, 1.405, 1.564, 
0.963, 0.751, 0.768, 0.572, 0.406, 0.423, 0.473, 0.028, -0.262, 
-0.329, 0.247, 0.354, -0.374, -0.533, -0.518, -1.078, -0.979, 
-1.451, -1.346, -1.092, -0.623, -1.076, -0.933, -1.126, -0.929, 
-0.858, -1.154, -1.101, -0.949, -0.66, -0.668, -0.963, -1.216, 
-1.046, -0.85, -1.171, -0.956, -1.665, -1.614, -2.083, -1.4, 
-0.769, -0.754, -0.722, -1.175, -0.749, -0.675, -0.726, -1.171, 
-1.019, -1.128, -1.299, -1.006, -0.868, -0.813, -1.029, -0.829, 
-0.582, -0.149, -0.458, -0.491, -0.744, -1.016, -0.718, -0.212, 
-0.582, -0.664, -1.057, -1.162, -1.049, -0.106, 0.177, 0.42, 
0.27, 0.258, 0.311, -0.022, 0.518, 0.802, 0.705, 0.803, 0.845, 
1.2, 1.291, 0.945, 1.99, 1.323, 1.087, 2.341, 1.912, 2.038, 1.924, 
1.685, 1.785, 1.938, 2.036, 1.018, 1.438, 2.256, 1.351, 1.928, 
1.241, 0.807, 2.479, 0.405, 1.693, 0.802, 3.652, 1.924, 0.655, 
1.289, 1.716, 0.657, 1.896, 1.443, 2.129, 2.277, 1.834, 3.133
), precip = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), bat = c(12.51, 
12.55, 12.59, 12.65, 12.72, 12.81, 12.93, 13.06, 13.21, 13.37, 
13.51, 13.64, 13.67, 13.65, 13.58, 13.57, 13.53, 13.53, 13.54, 
13.53, 13.54, 13.53, 13.54, 13.54, 13.54, 13.54, 13.54, 13.54, 
13.56, 13.56, 13.59, 13.58, 13.53, 13.56, 13.55, 13.54, 13.54, 
13.55, 13.5, 13.46, 13.47, 13.45, 13.41, 13.43, 13.41, 13.39, 
13.4, 13.43, 13.44, 13.42, 13.38, 13.47, 13.42, 13.47, 13.48, 
13.48, 13.47, 13.46, 13.49, 13.48, 13.49, 13.48, 13.47, 13.16, 
13, 12.97, 12.95, 12.93, 12.92, 12.91, 12.9, 12.89, 12.88, 12.87, 
12.87, 12.85, 12.85, 12.84, 12.84, 12.83, 12.82, 12.81, 12.81, 
12.8, 12.8, 12.79, 12.78, 12.78, 12.77, 12.77, 12.76, 12.75, 
12.75, 12.74, 12.73, 12.73, 12.72, 12.71, 12.71, 12.7, 12.7, 
12.69, 12.68, 12.68, 12.67, 12.66, 12.66, 12.65, 12.64, 12.64, 
12.63, 12.63, 12.62, 12.62, 12.61, 12.61, 12.6, 12.6, 12.59, 
12.59, 12.58, 12.58, 12.58, 12.57, 12.56, 12.56, 12.56, 12.56, 
12.55, 12.55, 12.55, 12.54, 12.54, 12.53, 12.53, 12.52, 12.52, 
12.51, 12.51, 12.51, 12.51, 12.51, 12.5, 12.5, 12.51, 12.54, 
12.58, 12.64, 12.72, 12.81, 12.93, 13.07, 13.22, 13.39, 13.54, 
13.68, 13.67, 13.67, 13.64, 13.57, 13.53, 13.56, 13.55, 13.55, 
13.55, 13.54, 13.55, 13.61, 13.61, 13.6, 13.59, 13.59, 13.61, 
13.62, 13.63, 13.62, 13.61, 13.61, 13.56, 13.55, 13.58, 13.52, 
13.56, 13.55, 13.51, 13.5, 13.49, 13.45, 13.42, 13.46, 13.42, 
13.42, 13.43, 13.44, 13.37, 13.37, 13.4, 13.41, 13.38, 13.46), 
    day = structure(c(17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 
    17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 
    17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 
    17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 
    17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 
    17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 
    17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 
    17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 
    17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 
    17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 
    17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 
    17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 
    17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17336, 
    17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 
    17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 
    17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 
    17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 
    17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 
    17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 
    17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 
    17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 
    17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 
    17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336), class = "Date"), fechahora = structure(c(1497762600, 
    1497763200, 1497763800, 1497764400, 1497765000, 1497765600, 
    1497766200, 1497766800, 1497767400, 1497768000, 1497768600, 
    1497769200, 1497769800, 1497770400, 1497771000, 1497771600, 
    1497772200, 1497772800, 1497773400, 1497774000, 1497774600, 
    1497775200, 1497775800, 1497776400, 1497777000, 1497777600, 
    1497778200, 1497778800, 1497779400, 1497780000, 1497780600, 
    1497781200, 1497781800, 1497782400, 1497783000, 1497783600, 
    1497784200, 1497784800, 1497785400, 1497786000, 1497786600, 
    1497787200, 1497787800, 1497788400, 1497789000, 1497789600, 
    1497790200, 1497790800, 1497791400, 1497792000, 1497792600, 
    1497793200, 1497793800, 1497794400, 1497795000, 1497795600, 
    1497796200, 1497796800, 1497797400, 1497798000, 1497798600, 
    1497799200, 1497799800, 1497800400, 1497801000, 1497801600, 
    1497802200, 1497802800, 1497803400, 1497804000, 1497804600, 
    1497805200, 1497805800, 1497806400, 1497807000, 1497807600, 
    1497808200, 1497808800, 1497809400, 1497810000, 1497810600, 
    1497811200, 1497811800, 1497812400, 1497813000, 1497813600, 
    1497814200, 1497814800, 1497815400, 1497816000, 1497816600, 
    1497817200, 1497817800, 1497818400, 1497819000, 1497819600, 
    1497820200, 1497820800, 1497821400, 1497822000, 1497822600, 
    1497823200, 1497823800, 1497824400, 1497825000, 1497825600, 
    1497826200, 1497826800, 1497827400, 1497828000, 1497828600, 
    1497829200, 1497829800, 1497830400, 1497831000, 1497831600, 
    1497832200, 1497832800, 1497833400, 1497834000, 1497834600, 
    1497835200, 1497835800, 1497836400, 1497837000, 1497837600, 
    1497838200, 1497838800, 1497839400, 1497840000, 1497840600, 
    1497841200, 1497841800, 1497842400, 1497843000, 1497843600, 
    1497844200, 1497844800, 1497845400, 1497846000, 1497846600, 
    1497847200, 1497847800, 1497848400, 1497849000, 1497849600, 
    1497850200, 1497850800, 1497851400, 1497852000, 1497852600, 
    1497853200, 1497853800, 1497854400, 1497855000, 1497855600, 
    1497856200, 1497856800, 1497857400, 1497858000, 1497858600, 
    1497859200, 1497859800, 1497860400, 1497861000, 1497861600, 
    1497862200, 1497862800, 1497863400, 1497864000, 1497864600, 
    1497865200, 1497865800, 1497866400, 1497867000, 1497867600, 
    1497868200, 1497868800, 1497869400, 1497870000, 1497870600, 
    1497871200, 1497871800, 1497872400, 1497873000, 1497873600, 
    1497874200, 1497874800, 1497875400, 1497876000, 1497876600, 
    1497877200, 1497877800, 1497878400, 1497879000, 1497879600, 
    1497880200, 1497880800, 1497881400, 1497882000), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), .Names = c("cod", "year", "dayofyear", 
"hour", "tempc", "relhum", "velwind", "dirwind", "sigwd", "sigwv", 
"vmaxwind", "u", "v", "precip", "bat", "day", "fechahora"), row.names = 233336:233535, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Just found a subset solution with `subset(datos.year, datos.year$day == today())` but would like to use `filter` from `lubridate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ***`dplyr::filter`*** and ***`lubridate::today`***.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

filtered.data <- 
                datos.year %>% 
                              dplyr::filter(day == lubridate::today())
```